# subsetting a dataframe in R - unexpected results

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

OK, couldn't find a better title

Let's say I have my_dataframe:

```
Name Value1 Value2
AA    10     20
BB    15     30
```

if I do:
`nrow(my_dataframe[my_dataframe$Value2>20,]`
I get '1' as result

I want to create my_second_dataframe, such as there's only column 'Value2':

```
my_second_dataframe<- my_dataframe[,'Value2', drop=FALSE]
```

let me check it out:

```
class(my_second_dataframe)
[1] "data.frame"
class(my_second_dataframe$Value2)
[1] "numeric"
```

but then:

```
nrow(my_second_dataframe[my_second_dataframe$Value2>20,]
NULL
```

?????
This would be part of a function, in which I want to isolate a column of choice and also get number of rows of that column based on a threshold number. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: In the first case you used `drop=FALSE`, why you didn't use that for the second one `my_second_dataframe[my_second_dataframe$Value2>20,, drop=FALSE]`  As there is only one column, it gets convert from data.frame to `vector`.  Or you can use `subset(my_second_dataframe, Value2>20)`

Comment: Hi, thank you. Adding 'drop=FALSE' does work. I still don't understand though. When I check the row number on the original data set I don't need to specify the drop parameter. 
Besides, I don't trust the subset function (see warnings)

Comment: By default, in `subset`, it is `drop=FALSE`, but if you are using the `[`, it is `drop=TRUE`.  You can see more details from `?Extract`

Comment: OK, I read again your first comment, my bad. I have made up an additional column for my_second_dataframe, and now the command works without the need to add drop. So, basically, when  there is only one column, it gets converted from data.frame to vector (as you said...). I did not know that! <censored_cussing> Well, thanks for your kind help :) Shame I cannot mark a comment as accepted answer.

Comment: In addition to akrun's comment, you might find useful `?NROW` (instead of `nrow`) too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the documentation in `?Extract`

> drop : For matrices and arrays. If TRUE the result is coerced to the
>   lowest possible dimension (see the examples). This only works for
>   extracting elements, not for the replacement. See drop for further
>   details.

Also, by default it is `drop = TRUE` for `[`

```
x[i, j, ... , drop = TRUE]
```

So, we need to specify `drop = FALSE` to avoid coercing to lowest possible dimension when there is only a single column or row.

In the OP's example

```
my_second_dataframe[my_second_dataframe$Value2>20,, drop=FALSE]
```